# PostgreSQL: calculating multiple averages in one query

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to calculate an average amount of money spent per day for the past 7, 30, 90 and 180 days. I know how to do it using PL/pgSQL, but I'd prefer to do it in one query if possible. Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)/days
FROM transactions
WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - ((days || ' day')::INTERVAL)
AND days = ANY(ARRAY[7,30,90,180]);
```

`ERROR:  column "days" does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unnest` to convert the array into a table and the use a correlated subquery to calculate the average:

```
SELECT
    days,
    (SELECT SUM(amount)/days
     FROM transactions
     WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - ((days || ' day')::INTERVAL)
    ) AS average
FROM unnest(ARRAY[7,30,90,180]) t(days)
```